# how to add a dot above $\imath$

Tags: math-mode

I want to indicate an element from a set of elements, so I want to use $i$ for the indication. I saw some books use a special shape for the indication in my case $i$. After quick search, I found out this symbol $\imath$ but without dot. I want add dot above it. For example,

> The robot can observe an ith landmark $L^{i}$ at a time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `$\dot{\imath}$` perhaps?

Comment: `\dot{\imath}` but that is almost never used as it looks like `i`

Comment: could you possibly scan an example and post the image in your question so that we can see how this differs from the "usual" italic *i* as used in math?

Comment: @barbarabeeton, sorry I don't remember which book that I was reading but @Mico guided me to `\iota`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to `$\imath$`, there's a second "dotless i" character -- the lowercase *Greek* letter `$\iota$`. (Well, there's also the Turkish dotless-i character, but I'll assume that it's *not* what you found in the books.)

Here are some possibilities. Note that it's not easy to distinguish `$\dot{imath}$` from `$i$`, i.e., the "ordinary" math-italic "i", in a typeset document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\imath, \dot{\imath}, i$: \verb+  \imath, \dot{\imath}, i+

$\iota, \dot{\iota}$: \verb+   \iota, \dot{\iota}+
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is `\iota` what I'm looking for.

Comment: @CroCo - I'm glad that my guess -- that it's the `\iota` character you were looking for -- was correct.